# Accessing a numeric property in a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to access the number in the below element, but I'm having trouble getting the value out of it.

```
echo $object->0; //returns Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [0:public] => 15810
)
```

Any ideas on how I can get that value?

**Update**

I realize that this is an odd error... I'm using the ebay API to get this value.  Even when I do:

```
  $zero = 0;
  $print_r($ruleXml->HourlyUsage->$zero);
```

It still shows the same

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [0:public] => 15810
)
```

I tried `{0}` as well

Here's the output of what I'm working with....

```
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [CallName:public] => AddItem
        [CountsTowardAggregate:public] => false
        [DailyHardLimit:public] => 100000
        [DailySoftLimit:public] => 100000
        [DailyUsage:public] => 0
        [HourlyHardLimit:public] => 100000
        [HourlySoftLimit:public] => 100000
        [HourlyUsage:public] => 0
        [Period:public] => -1
        [PeriodicHardLimit:public] => 0
        [PeriodicSoftLimit:public] => 0
        [PeriodicUsage:public] => 0
        [ModTime:public] => 2010-05-04T18:06:08.000Z
        [RuleCurrentStatus:public] => NotSet
        [RuleStatus:public] => RuleOn
    )
```

So here's the thing...

```
number_format($ruleXml->HourlyUsage) //throws the error: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, object given

$ruleXml->HourlyUsage //shows the value on the page
```

Comment: Post a sample of the source XML, or a link to it. Otherwise, it's akin to divination. Also, never use print_r() to inspect a SimpleXMLElement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$x = 0;
echo $object->$x;
```

or

```
echo $object->{0};
```

The reason is that '0' is not a valid identifier in PHP.  So when you type '0', all it sees is a T_LNUMBER.  All names follow the varaible naming convention.  The only deviation is that a member variable preceded by a -> does not need the $ prefix.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

{0} works, because {} indicates that the identifier is the result of the simple expression inside.  So {$x} is the same as $x in this case, but {0} is not the same as '0', since they result in different parser tokens.

Comment: Have you actually got that working? I highly doubt it would give the desired result.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't work at all on PHP 5.3.2 / libxml 2.7.7.

Comment: $x = 0;
echo $object->$x;
Works.
echo $object->{0};
Doesn't work.

Comment: @TOOTSKI yes, I can (from master all the way back to 5.0.0): http://3v4l.org/8pKE1 It's how you construct the class that matters. Casting from an array changes numeric keys in bad ways (and buggy). Whereas this question was about *objects* with numeric keys, not casted arrays...

Comment: @ircmaxell Could you describe or point to bad and buggy ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that business about nodes named "0" but the error you're seeing is because SimpleXML always returns objects. If you have to use the result as a number, cast it to the appropriate type, e.g.

```
number_format((int) $ruleXml->HourlyUsage)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__toString()` to get string value of child object ,so it will be like `$object->__toString();`

Answer (score 0):

[XML elements cannot begin with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-name). Even if you can somehow create such elements, SimpleXML (and most likely, most parsers) will not be able to read the result document.

```
<!-- legal -->
<a0>foo</a0>

<!-- not legal -- note how even Stack Overflow's highlighter chokes on it -->
<0>foo</0>
```