# SimpleXML PHP Variable issue

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml

Below you will find my xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<app>
    <version>0925</version>
    <humanVersion>0.9.25</humanVersion>
</app>
```

Here is my php:

```
$completeurl = "ota/shingle/shingle.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
$updateVer = $xml->version;
$updateVerHuman = $xml->humanVersion;
```

I am taking the php variables and putting them into a json string, here is the output:

{"updateVer":{"0":"0925"},"updateVerHuman":{"0":"0.9.25"}}

Why is the updateVer and updateVerHuman data enclosed in {} and contains "0":?? I would like only the data in that value. How do I achieve this?

I have tried this but it produces the same result:

```
$updateVer = $xml->version[0];
$updateVerHuman = $xml->humanVersion[0];
```

Comment: Try getting the value of the property named "0" with `$xml->version->{0}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a numeric property in a SimpleXMLElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877656/accessing-a-numeric-property-in-a-simplexmlelement)

Comment: @sachleen You've misread the question - there is no property named "0" in the XML, it's appearing when they attempt to encode their extracted variables as JSON.

Comment: In other words it is the same as doing this: `$object = new StdClass;
$offset = 0;
$object->$offset = '1.2.3';
var_dump(json_encode($object));`

Comment: @ficuscr Yes, roughly. But bear in mind that SimpleXML objects are not "real" PHP objects, they are a bunch of methods and operators wrapped around a non-PHP data structure. The way they behave under various serializations can therefore be somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: Resolved using $updateVer = (string)$xml->version; $updateVerHuman = (string)$xml->humanVersion; 

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access any child element (or even attribute) with SimpleXML, you get back another SimpleXML object - this is why you can write things like `$node->child->grand_child`.

In order to get just the string content of a particular bit of XML, you need to "cast" the SimpleXML object to a string, using `(string)$variable`.

Sometimes, this will happen for you - notably, since you can't echo anything other than a string, `echo $variable` will always cast to a string for you. However, **as a rule of thumb, always cast SimpleXML objects to string** to avoid later confusion.

In your example, `$updateVer` and `$updateVerHuman` are both still objects when you turn them to JSON. `$updateVer = (string)$xml->version; $updateVerHuman = (string)$xml->humanVersion;` should give the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I just ran into this problem when trying to access an array using a variable key that I recieved from SimpleXML and couldn't figure out why I was getting    Warning: Illegal offset type.  I just assumed (bad!) that it was a string since I could echo it.